# Problem captcha Asp.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a captcha in my MVC application that is called from a HttpHandler (.ashx).

It works fine in Visual Studio developer server.

I just configure in Global.asax:

```
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {    
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{filename}.ashx/{*pathInfo}");//captcha

.........
```

It ignores the follow path in Visual Studio developer server:

```
http://localhost:5011/captcha.ashx?id=2342556fgh767896sa
```

Problem is now i'm running the application in IIS 7.Now the path to be ignored has changed to:

```
http://localhost/Sce/captcha.ashx?id=2342556fgh767896sa
```

And it doesn't work anymore.

Any ideas to ignore the new path?

**UPDATE:**

I´ve solved my problem.Need to add the handler in web.config,but not in `<httpHandler>` section.Must be in `<system.webserver>` section cause im using IIS 7.0

Comment: Why are you using a HttpHandler in ASP.NET MVC anyway? Actions/ActionFilters/ActionResults provide everything you'll need to do it within the framework.

Comment: because i dont know how to implement captcha without handlers.I dont want to use Recaptcha.

Comment: You can basically just write a custom action result the deals directly with HttpContext, then return it from an action. Here is an example the might help http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=484

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the handler to the `system.webserver` section of your `web.config`.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{allashx}", new {allashx=@".*\.ashx(/.*)?"});
```

Order is important.  Put this first before your controller routes.

Comment: it doenst work.But i guess that its correct.Must be another problem.