# CaptchaMvc mvc5 image not shows when publish to iis server

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, iis, captcha

I am using CaptchaMvc.Mvc5 from nuget package on my project
it is works fine localy but not on production iis server

it happens only with **firefox**

my global.asax Application_Start method is like this:

```
    void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Code that runs on application startup
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

        // Removing all the view engines
        ViewEngines.Engines.Clear();
        //Add Razor Engine (which we are using)
        ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new RazorViewEngine());

        CaptchaUtils.CaptchaManager.StorageProvider = new CookieStorageProvider();

        //hide mvc header to improve security
        MvcHandler.DisableMvcResponseHeader = true;
    }
```

Do i have to add anything else? or make any config in my IIS server?
I am using IIS server version 6

thanks

Comment: Recently i encountered with same problem. Works on chrome but doesn't work on FF. 
Works perfectly on local dev server with FF but doesn't work on prod with FF.

Comment: How did you solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Did you check your Host services related permissions? Usually, the folder consisting the image files may have not required permission for changes, which is important for captcha since it changes image file.

EDIT:
take a look at this;
[Problem captcha Asp.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3744153/problem-captcha-asp-net-mvc)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. After hours of debugging it turns out antivirus on the server blocks access to required files.